# TypeScript type for initial empty object

Tags: typescript

I am having problems with TypeScript on this code which works well on normal JS

I get this error form TypeScript:

```
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'`
```

```js
const data = [{
  Department: 'HR',
  Name: 'Tom'
},{
  Department: 'Finance',
  Name: 'Peter'
},{
  Department: 'HR',
  Name: 'Jane'
}]

const groups = {}
for (const { Name, Department } of data) {
  if (!groups[Department]) groups[Department] = { title: Department, people: [] }
  groups[Department].people.push(Name)
}
console.log(Object.values(groups))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I have tried to add the Props

```
type Props = {
  title?: string
  people?: string[]
}

const groups: Props | undefined = {}
```

But I still get a similar error

```
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Props'.`
```

Comment: `groups: { [key: string]: { title: string, people: string[] } } = {};` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJxAVwA4QFwwN4wNoDWApgJ5bQICWYcAulrlJVADZHlRU0A0MqRIVGw5c4eWjAC+UmAF4ckgNwAoRCnR4A5AHcAFgEMoRAG5EEmifMbNhMHQaOnzvfoNvipKoA

Comment: Thanks it also worked with `const groups: { [key: string]: Props } = {}`

Comment: There is a utility type Record<Keys, Values> which is a shorthand for the “[key: string]:” index.  You can use Record<string, Props> if that’s more readable.  Functionally it’s the same.  It means an object whose keys are type string and whose values are type Props.  Also I would make the properties on Props required rather than optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
type Department = { [name: string]: { title: string; people: string[] } };

const groups: Department = {};
```